# Word- VBA- Why Does Placeholder Text Change After I Enter Values Into Content Control?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code works successfully to insert a Content Control Rich Text with placeholder text "test1" in Arial, 8 font, red and italic.  However, once you enter text into the content control, the placeholder font, size and color change back to default settings.

How do I prevent the placeholder text from changing back to default settings?

```
Dim oTable As Table
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim oNewRow As Row
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows.Add
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(1)
    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, oCell.Range)
    With oCC
        .DefaultTextStyle = "Style1"
        .Tag = "Test1"
        .Setplaceholdertext , , "test1"
        If oCC.ShowingPlaceholderText Then
            With oCC.Range.Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 8
                .ColorIndex = wdRed
                .Italic = True
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The logic, I suspect, is that the formatting is applied to a range. In a new control the range might consist of 1 or 0 chars. When the user selects the control, what - exactly - does he select? If he selects the formatted range whatever he types will assume the format you gave. But if he just placed the cursor in the control there is no selection and whatever he types will be next to the range you formatted, not on it. Accordingly, the solution would either be to either control what is selected on *Enter* or change the default settings for each control individually (if that is possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim oTable As Table
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim oNewRow As Row
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows.Add
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(1)
    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, oCell.Range)
    With oCC
        .DefaultTextStyle = "Style1"
        .Tag = "Test1"
        .Setplaceholdertext , , "test1"
        If oCC.ShowingPlaceholderText Then
            **With ActiveDocument.Styles("Placeholder Text").Font**
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 8
                .ColorIndex = wdRed
                .Italic = True
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of the placeholder text is defined by the style 'Placeholder Text'.

If you want the text of a content control to have specific formatting after text has been entered you can assign a style to the `DefaultTextStyle` property.

Comment: I have assigned .DefaultTextStyle = "Style1" to the content control. Where can I assign a style to placeholder text so it doesn't reset to the default style after entering values?

Comment: Wow.....I am special.  However, the only way I could get it to work was to use ```With ActiveDocument.Styles("Placeholder Text").Font``` in place of ```With oCC.Range.Font``` which sets the placeholder text for the whole document.  How  do I do just that particular cell?

Comment: The whole point of Placeholder Text is that it is supposed to look different from the completed text. It shows the user that there is something to fill in. If for some reason you don't want to follow that convention just use the code in your question.

Comment: Sorry.  Let me clarify.  I want to have different placeholder text styles within the same document but ```With ActiveDocument.Styles("Placeholder Text").Font``` sets the placeholder text for the whole document and ```With oCC.Range.Font``` won't let me assign a style.

Comment: Like I said, use the code in your question.

Comment: ```With oCC.Range.Style("Placeholder Text").Font``` works but I get "Run-Time Error 451: Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object".  Don't know what that means.